# How to use adoptedStyleSheets in lit

Tags: lit

Refer to this document,

https://lit.dev/docs/api/styles/#adoptStyles

I am not able to figure out the way to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like I can use following way to do the import.

```
import styleSheet from '@material/data-table/dist/mdc.data-table.css' assert { type: 'css' };

connectedCallback() {
  super.connectedCallback();
  this.renderRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [styleSheet];
}
```

Comment: Using above solution, component CSS is overriding (component CSS is getting removed)
how to resolve this?

Comment: @abhijeet_shela I meant you since you commented, see my newer answer.

Comment: This works for regular CSS, but you will need to use [construct-style-sheets-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/construct-style-sheets-polyfill) for it to work on older browsers that don't support adoptedStyleSheets. If you want to import styles from an other Lit component that uses the css template literal tag, and therefore returns a CSSResult, you should use Lit's adoptStyles as shown by @PierreHenry.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the correct way to use the `adoptStyles` function is as follows (example is TS, should be straightforward to strip type data for plain JS):

```
import styles from './styles.css';

export class MyElement extends LitElement {

  static override styles = css`
    button {
      color: green;
    }
  `;

  override connectedCallback () {
    super.connectedCallback();
    adoptStyles(this.renderRoot as ShadowRoot, [ styles, DisclosureLitElement.styles ]);
  }
}
```

That way, both the imported styles and the local styles are applied.

Comment: This is great and totally works as expected. No need to use [construct-style-sheets-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/construct-style-sheets-polyfill) either.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `static get styles` inside your `class`

```js
import { adoptStyles, LitElement } from 'lit';

class youComp extends LitElement {
  static get styles(){
    return [adoptStyles] /* you can return array of styles */
  }
}
```

This should do the job

Comment: could you provide details sample, couldn't imaging the usage with current code.

Comment: @王子1986 go through lit official documentation of styles usage. They have a clear documentation on the same `https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/styles#expressions`

Comment: apparently that's not I am looking for. Instead of styles, I am asking details about adoptStyles usage.